# Python ssh with fabric, code 127

Tags: python, windows, ssh, fabric, ros

I'm trying to use fabric in python to send commands to a program on another machine.

This code works fine:

```
from fabric.api import env, run

env.host_string = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
env.user = 'username'
env.password = 'password'

run('ls')
```

But when running

```
run('rostopic list')
```

I get

```
Warning: run() received nonzero return code 127 while executing 'rostopic list'!
'/bin/bash: rostopic: command not found'
```

However on the machine itself if I run

```
rostopic list
```

it runs as it's supposed to

I'm not sure how to proceed and I don't understand why it's not working with fabric. FYI I tried implementing this with paramiko but I also run into problems, however it works fine with pxssh. The issue is that I need this to work on Windows and pxssh isn't compatible. How can I make this command work with fabric?

Comment: Are you sure the shell environment for the SSH session is correct? Like you're running `/bin/sh` compared to `/bin/bash`?

Comment: How do I run it in /bin/sh? I'm not sure how to change the shell environment. Until now I have been running these commands in the python command line

Comment: It may already be running in `/bin/sh`. That's my point, is that `bash` could have different PATH environment, therefore allowing you to run the command

Comment: Actually it does say 'bin/bash: rostopic: command not found'

Comment: So how do I change the environment to /bin/sh?

Comment: So, you'll need to determine which shell & user to login to that makes `rostopic list` work as if it's the same environmental

Comment: One way would be `run('/bin/sh -c "rostopic list"')`, but no guarantees that'll work. I'd think `bash` is what you want

Comment: using that command gives me the same code 127 error, but with
'list: 1: list: rostopic: not found'

Comment: Hmm... Not sure about that. Found the documentation, by the way. http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#faq-bash Anyways, you can `echo $PATH` both through fabric and in the actual machine to see if there's any differences. Maybe run `which rostopic` on the machine to see where the command is located.

Comment: So I found where it was located and ran
`run('/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rostopic list')`
but I get `Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rostopic", line 34, in <module>\r\n import rostopic\r\nImportError: No module named rostopic`

Comment: Well, that's better than command not found, I guess...

Comment: When you SSH into run the remote machine and run the `rostopic list` command, do you need to be in a certain directory in order for it to work? If so, you might need to use [Fabric's `cd` context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html).

Comment: The problem was that when using ssh, the `$PATH` used by fabric isn't the same as the `$PATH` the remote machine uses. So ssh with fabric didn't recognize the command `rostopic`. I was able to fix this using `env.path = 'opt/ros/indigo/bin/'` to add rostopic to the `$PATH`.
But now I'm having a similar problem because rostopic is a python module, and by issuing a command through ssh it doesn't see all the modules that the remote machine sees... So it gives me the `ImportError` above

Comment: One idea: You should try using the `path` context manager instead of setting `env.path` directly (see those same docs linked above). It will append that `/opt/ros/indigo/bin/` path to the existing `$PATH`, rather than stomping/overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you've made about the pathing issues, it sounds like you will need to use some combination of the [`path`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.path), [`cd`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd), and/or [`prefix`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.prefix) context managers in order to run [ROS (Robot Operating System)](http://wiki.ros.org/) commands over an SSH connection. You might also wish to troubleshoot by getting Fabric completely out of the picture, and instead work on getting the command to work via `ssh -t`, like so:

```
$ ssh user@machine -t "cd /my/home/directory && /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rostopic list"
```

An example using context managers with Fabric would look like this:

```
with path('/opt/ros/indigo/bin/'):
    with prefix('always run this command'):
        with cd('/my/special/directory'):
            run('rostopic list')
```

That's pretty contrived, but hopefully illustrates the point. Regardless, I would first make sure that you can run the command via `ssh -t`. Solving that problem will likely lead you to the correct way to make this happen with Fabric.

As a side/related consideration: is this a virtual environment on your remote machine? You could use the `prefix` context manager to activate it, like so:

```
with prefix('/opt/ros/indigo/bin/activate'):
    run('rostopic list')
```

Or using `ssh -t`, you could execute:

```
$ ssh user@machine -t "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/activate && rostopic list"
```

Comment: I need this to work in windows though.. Also I've been toying around with plink.exe and it turns out that `rostopic` commands work when I run `plink -pw password user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to use an interactive shell. However If I send the commands directly with `plink -pw password user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx rostopic list` I have the same error with `bash: rostopic: command not found`